# windows screen capture tool that supports on-event mouse click

Tags: windows

I need a windows screen capture tool that supports an on-event mouse click capture.  I want to set up the tool to capture a region on the screen every time a left mouse click is detected on any part of the screen.

The closest I found is Snappy  https://www.addictivetips.com/windows-tips/snappy-capture-screenshots-on-time-mouse-keyboard-events/

but I had issues with it and is also very old.

If you know of a portable version that would be even better.

thanks.